# Computing large numbers outside of predefined number types

Tags: go

I was working on a Fibonacci number generator as part of a homework assignment. It becomes impossible to represent the output of these Fibonacci numbers in predefined numeric types such as int32 within Go, you have to use something like this to deal with the massive numbers:
https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/

If we change the ask of the problem slightly and instead of asking for the result of the 1,000th Fibonacci number, we instead ask for the last digit of that same number, Go can handle this without issue.

My questions are:

1. Is Go able to do calculations of very large numbers because of the language's ability to expand the stack size when more memory is needed as the numbers start to get very large? Where / how is it storing these numbers when they start to become so big they won't fit into a 32, or 64 bit integer type in memory?
2. If Go is able to do calculations on huge numbers that will not fit into a basic type like int32, why does the language force you to store these numbers in a basic type that is too small to handle them? For example, if Go is able to add together two massively large numbers and determine a result seemingly without issue, why can't I store this value for future use or print it to the screen without using another library? I guess I am not sure why numbers have to fit into a predefined size when trying to do something like print them to the screen if behind the scenes Go is able to do operations on them just fine.

Here is some example code where I store and print the last digit of the nth Fibonacci number as opposed to printing out the actual value of the nth term because the numbers get so large. Note how I am still preforming the addition of these massive numbers in the append statement, but just store the last digit.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var n int
    var fibNums = []int{0, 1}
    var i int

    fmt.Scanln(&n)

    for i = 0; i < n; i++ {
        fibNums = append(fibNums, (fibNums[i]+fibNums[i+1])%10)
    }

    fmt.Println(fibNums[len(fibNums)-2])
}
```

Comment: For #2 -- your fibNums array is only ever storing numbers < 10, since you're appending the result of the modulo. This gives you the right answer in the end, because only the last digit of each term matters when looking for the last digit of the nth, but you're not actually storing or adding the large numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is Go able to do calculations of very large numbers because of the language's ability to expand the stack size when more memory is needed as the numbers start to get very large? Where / how is it storing these numbers when they start to become so big they won't fit into a 32, or 64 bit integer type in memory?

Sort of - it's able to do it because when you use `math.Big`, it is essentially storing each number as a slice of `uint`, along with some extra fields (e.g. the sign of the number), where each item in the slice represents a *single digit* of the number.

> If Go is able to do calculations on huge numbers that will not fit into a basic type like int32, why does the language force you to store these numbers in a basic type that is too small to handle them?

The language *doesn't* force you to store them in that type - you are free to use `math.Big` for all of your numbers.  But generally, we want our code to run quickly, and the amount of work necessary to do:

```
x := 21
y := 29
z := x + y
```

is very little, and it will run very quickly.  But it's a tradeoff - you just have to realize that something as simple as that, when storing each digit in a slice, becomes many more steps.  As a quick demo: (https://play.golang.org/p/rFWKbKy4FeQ):

```
x := []uint{2,1}
y := []uint{2,9}
result := []uint{}
xIndex := len(x) - 1
yIndex := len(y) - 1
carry := 0
for ; xIndex >= 0 || yIndex >= 0; {
    z := uint(0)
    if xIndex >= 0 && yIndex >= 0 {
        z = x[xIndex] + y[yIndex]
    } else if xIndex >= 0 {
        z = x[xIndex]
    } else {
        z = y[yIndex]
    }
    if carry != 0 {
        z++
    }
    if z >= 10 {
        carry = 1
        z = z % 10
    }
    xIndex--
    yIndex--
    result = append([]uint{z}, result...)
}
fmt.Println(result)
```

I'll still get the right answer (in this case, I haven't even worried about any edge cases yet), but there's just a lot more work.  If every math operation required this much work, Go would not be considered a fast language.

Answer (score -1):

> Is Go able to do calculations of very large numbers because of the language's ability to expand the stack size when more memory is needed as the numbers start to get very large?

No, stack and math/big are totally unrelated.

> Where / how is it storing these numbers when they start to become so big they won't fit into a 32, or 64 bit integer type in memory?

"Where": Nobody knows. Go, the language makes no claims/guarantees on "where" things are stored. Normal computers have a stack and a heap and the two most common Go compilers decide where to put your math/big.Int. This decision is made for each variable individually. Note that different compiler versions may decide differently. (Google for "escape analysis" for details). You may assume that math/big.Int are stored in the heap.

"How": Read the source of math/big.Int :-) Basically in several primitive integers. See https://golang.org/src/math/big/nat.go#L23 (roughly as you encode a number > 9 in decimal).

> If Go is able to do calculations on huge numbers that will not fit into a basic type like int32, why does the language force you to store these numbers in a basic type that is too small to handle them?

This question makes the assumption "the language force you to store these numbers in a basic type that is too small to handle them" that is false. The "largest" integer type in Go is uint64 and if this is not sufficient you can use math/big.Int and nobody forces you to store a math/big.Int in one of the primitive types.

> For example, if Go is able to add together two massively large numbers and determine a result seemingly without issue, why can't I store this value for future use or print it to the screen without using another library?

Assuming with "Go" you mean the primitive builtin types: No, this Go cannot do calculations on numbers that do not fit into the used primitive type. To do correct calculations on "massively large numbers" you have to use package math/big.

Note that your "last digit of Fibonacci number is **plain** **wrong** once one number overflows int (typically 9223372036854775807). Primitive types in Go over-/underflow (look up the exact details in the spec) in which case the result is well defined but no longer what you expect  it to be.

(Side note: Go's treatment of constants is different.)